# Ionic 3/4 base64 image fails to display on device but works on localhost

Tags: android, image, ionic-framework, base64

Ionic 3/4 small base64 image, hard coded in the .ts file displays on localhost but fails to display on Android device, just shows the basic missing image icon/box

Comment: Are u using capacitor or cordova?

Comment: Sorry, Cordova, its an old project, I have tried a 1 pixel jpg in the assets and assetts/imgs folder and then stored a base64 version of the image in a variable and set src="this.imageHolding"   Works on localhost..